# Anyway to test the TFS Api without installing local TFS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs

I need to write a proof of concept with the TFS API (fetching data from tfs server regarding workitems and put this data in our tables).

Can Any body suggest a way to do this without setting up my own TFS Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set up one on the MS Cloud TFS which is now on [tfs.visualstudio.com](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/) (previously called TFSPreview.com.

> With TFS, your code is accessible from anywhere. You can check in code
>   directly from Visual Studio and Eclipse, or you can use command-line
>   tools to check in your code from Xcode and other IDEs. Since it's all
>   in the cloud, your team can get started quickly with no infrastructure
>   to manage.